# Good type design in Haskell for the AST of a simple language

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm new to Haskell, and am working through the [Haskell LLVM tutorial](http://www.stephendiehl.com/llvm/). In it, the author defines a simple algebraic data type to represent the AST.

```
type Name = String

data Expr
  = Float Double
  | BinOp Op Expr Expr
  | Var String
  | Call Name [Expr]
  | Function Name [Expr] Expr
  | Extern Name [Expr]
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data Op
  = Plus
  | Minus
  | Times
  | Divide
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

However, this is not an ideal structure, because the parser actually expects that the list of `Expr` in an `Extern` will only ever contain expressions representing variables (i.e. parameters in this situation cannot be arbitrary expressions). I would like to make the types reflect this constraint (making it easier to generate random valid ASTs using QuickCheck); however, for the sake of consistency in the parser functions (which all have type `Parser Expr`), I don't just want to say `| Expr Name [Name]`. I would like to do something like this:

```
data Expr
  = ...
  | Var String
    ...
  | Function Name [Expr] Expr
  | Extern Name [Var] -- enforce constraint here
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

But it's not possible in Haskell.

To summarize, `Extern` and `Var` should both be `Expr`, and `Extern` should have a list of `Vars` representing parameters. Would the best way be to split all of these out and make them instances of an `Expr` typeclass (that wouldn't have any methods)? Or is there a more idiomatic method (or would it be better to scrap these types and do something totally different)?

Comment: Your `| Extern Name [Name]` solution is the way to go. What do you dislike about it? It's perfectly natural for different parsing functions to return different types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of the LLVM tutorial you mentioned.

Just use `Extern Name [Name]`, everything after Chapter 3 onward in the tutorial uses that [exact definition](https://github.com/sdiehl/kaleidoscope/blob/master/src/chapter7/Syntax.hs#L22) anyways. I think I just forgot to make Chapter 2 `Syntax.hs` consistent with the others.

I wouldn't worry about making the parser definitions consistent, it's fine for them to return different types. Here's what the later parsers use. `identifier` is just the parsec builtin for the alphanumeric identifier from the LanguageDef that becomes the `Name` type in the AST.

```
extern :: Parser Expr
extern = do
  reserved "extern"
  name <- identifier
  args <- parens $ many identifier
  return $ Extern name args
```